# A* implementation does not work correctly

Tags: unity, 3d, path-finding

I'm trying to implement a 3D pathfinding system based on the A* algorithm. [This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZfyt03LDH4) served as the starting point for my implementation. I tried to remake it for pathfinding in three dimensions, but in some cases it starts to zigzag.

[image: zigzag]

It happens only when the path contains a row parallel to the Z axis. Otherwise, everything works fine.

[image: No zigzag]

This is how my algorithm looks for a way to destination:

```
public void FindNodePath(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos)
{
    Node startNode = _grid.GetNodeFromWorldPoint(startPos);
    Node targetNode = _grid.GetNodeFromWorldPoint(targetPos);
    List<Node> openSet = new List<Node>();
    HashSet<Node> closedSet = new HashSet<Node>();
    openSet.Add(startNode);
    while (openSet.Count > 0)
    {
        Node node = openSet[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < openSet.Count; i++)
        {
            if (openSet[i].FCost < node.FCost || openSet[i].FCost == node.FCost)
            {
                if (openSet[i].HCost < node.HCost)
                    node = openSet[i];
            }
        }
        openSet.Remove(node);
        closedSet.Add(node);
        if (node == targetNode)
        {
            RetracePath(startNode, targetNode);
            return;
        }
        foreach (Node neighbour in _grid.GetNeighbours(node))
        {
            if (!neighbour.IsWalkable || closedSet.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                continue;
            }
            float newCostToNeighbour = node.GCost + GetDistance(node, neighbour);
            if (newCostToNeighbour < neighbour.GCost || !openSet.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                neighbour.GCost = newCostToNeighbour;
                neighbour.HCost = GetDistance(neighbour, targetNode);
                neighbour.Parent = node;
                if (!openSet.Contains(neighbour))
                    openSet.Add(neighbour);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `RetracePath` method collects all path nodes in one list  which will be used later to draw gizmos. I also found the [explaination of 3D cost](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/185689/distance-cost-for-3d-a-algorithm) for this algorithm, so right now my implementation looks the same:

```
float GetDistance(Node current, Node target)
{
    int distX = Mathf.Abs(current.GridPosition.x - target.GridPosition.x);
    int distY = Mathf.Abs(current.GridPosition.y - target.GridPosition.y);
    int distZ = Mathf.Abs(current.GridPosition.z - target.GridPosition.z);
    int distMin = Mathf.Min(distX, distY, distZ);
    int distMax = Mathf.Max(distX, distY, distZ);
    int tripleAxis = distMin;
    int doubleAxis = Mathf.Max(distX + distY + distZ - distMax - 2 * distMin, 0);
    int singleAxis = distMax - doubleAxis - tripleAxis;
    return D1 * singleAxis + D2 * doubleAxis + D3 * tripleAxis;
}
```

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming that diagonal and horizontal cost are the same in your movement system, the path you have here is still optimal. When it's not the same cost, then your route finding algorithm doesn't seem to account for that. When your path is actually optimal but just doesn't look natural, then that's a sign that your heuristic is broken.

Comment: What are your `D1`, `D2`, and `D3` coefficients set to at the moment?

Comment: i fixed the project. the problem was in determining neighboring nodes. other parts of algirithm works correctly

Comment: If you solved your problem, be sure to share your solution as an Answer below.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author found out that their mistake was in a piece of code that wasn't included in the question.